# Atomic Boolean usage in multithreaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, context-switch

I am trying to run the following code:

In my constructor i initalize my atomic boolean:

```
Atomic Boolean isChannelActive = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

In my write method i check this boolean and wait:

```
public ChannelFuture write(ByteBuf msgBuf) {
if (!isChannelActive.get()) {
  try {
    wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    logger.Error("Waiting interrupted", ex);
  }
}
```

But the problem is this atomic boolean can be set from different thread at the time when program is on :

```
if (!isChannelActive.get()) { 
  try{ --- Right on here and program made a context switch at this time.
    wait()
```

So in this scenario my atomic boolean will be true and i miss the notifyAll() event and will be wait forever because of the context switch.

How can i prevent this problem?

I know that synchronized blocks may be the option but i am looking for more elegant option for this case.

Comment: If you're calling `wait()` you're already **in** a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Could [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) be an alternative?

Comment: I have also take another look at CountdownLatch mechanism and is also working fine. Same problem can be achieved with [CountdownLatches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix synchronization mechanisms from different levels.

1. `wait/notify` - This is an archaic system that you do not need to use anymore. Everything you can to with `wait/notify` can be done with `synchronized` or `Lock`s.
2. `synchronized` - this allows you to synchronise code so that sections that need exclusive access do not interfere with each other.
3. `Lock`s - There are various different types of locks that can generally handle almost any access control you like.
4. `Blocking...` - This is the more modern approach - it uses data structures to ensure safe access rather than putting the synchronisation in the code.
5. There are further sets of features such as `Phaser` and `Semaphore` that can be used to achieve some of the more common mechanisms.

You are attemptin to use `atomics` and `wait/notify` at the same time. This will not work without difficulties.

You probably just need a `Lock`.

```
Lock channelActive = new ReentrantLock();

public void test() {
    channelActive.lock();
    try {
        // Do your exclusive stuff here.
    } finally {
        channelActive.unlock();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling `wait()` you're already **in** a `synchronized` block. Your scenario is a hypothetical one, as both threads that call `wait()` and `notifyAll()` must have obtained the same object monitor.

Therefore it's impossible that there is a context switch at the place you claim[1]. There's also no advantage in using an `AtomicBoolean` here (at least based on what you've shown), a simple `volatile boolean` would work just as fine.

[1] Not impossible, you could write the code so the condition check is outside of a synchronized block, but that would be intentionally writing broken concurrent code.